# How do I Start html5 video paused then after user begins video then autoplay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, video-player

I've created a html5 video playlist. When the page first loads I want the video to be paused, so the user has the choice to begin the autoplay sequence.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var videoPlayer= document.getElementById('video');

videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function(){
this.pause();
this.src = "http://www.mp4point.com/downloads/8feeca1a540b.mp4";
}, false);

}//]]>  

</script> 


</head> 
<body> 
  <video id="video" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" autoplay autobuffer controls /> 

</body> 


</html>
```

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3uRq6/7/

Comment: use flowpayer for this task

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you need to reverse your logic.  Remove the `autoplay` attribute from the `<video>` and on your event listener you should change the `src` then play the video.

http://jsfiddle.net/3uRq6/9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var videoPlayer= document.getElementById('video');

videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    this.src = "http://www.mp4point.com/downloads/8feeca1a540b.mp4";
    this.play();
}, false);

}//]]>  

</script> 


</head> 
<body> 
  <video id="video" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" autobuffer controls /> 

</body> 


</html>
```